# Stop all activities and fragments of Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

To disconnect from the application i'm developing, i stop all activities and start the LoginActivity. To do so i'm using the code below. the LoginActivity is started but when i click the back button of my phone, i'm connected again without giving the login and password.

NB: I have also fragments in my app!

Can you help me pllz.

```
// After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` sets the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in the Intent flags. Then you do this:

```
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This sets the content of the Intent flags to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, thereby clearing the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` that you had previously set!

You don't need to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, as this won't actually start a new task (because your activities all have the same `taskAffinity`).

Setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` should be enough to do what you want. However, you will need to make sure that your `LoginActivity` is still active in the task (ie: you shouldn't have called `finish()` on it). If your `LoginActivity` isn't present in the activity stack of your task (because you have already called `finish()` on it), then Android will just create a new instance of `LoginActivity` and put it on top of the stack.